# How can I count the number of equal words between two strings?

Tags: xpath, xquery

How can I count the number of words that appear in two strings?

I'm thinking in something like this

```
      let $nequalwords := count($item[text() eq $speech])
```

What is the best way to do this?

I thought to go with a two `for`s comparing word by word, but I don't know if there are a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you try to count. I guess it would be reasonable to provide two example strings, the words to be counted and the final numeric result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about splitting the strings on white space so that you end up with words, and then creating a sequence of the strings and removing those that are not distinct, i.e. those that appear in both strings, by then subtracting this from the count of all words you know how many words appeared in both strings. For example:

```
  let $distinct-words1 := distinct-values(tokenize($string1, "\s+"))
  let $distinct-words2 := distinct-values(tokenize($string2, "\s+"))
  let $all-words := ($distinct-words1, $distinct-words2)
  return
    count($all-words) - count(distinct-values($all-words))
```

Comment: Doesn't this give the number of words that appear repeatedly in the concatenation of the two strings, rather than the number of words that appear in both?

Comment: I edited your query slightly, because I think it was incorrect XQuery (I also checked in exist, which gave the same compile error as BaseX).

Comment: @MichaelKay I might be misunderstanding you. I try to count the number of occurrences of words in string1 that also occur in string2, however I ignore duplicates within string1 and string2 as they are not distinct words, but I guess they could be considered distinct occurrences. Perhaps I misinterpreted what was required... it was not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Thanks @dirkk I composed this from my mobile in a bit of a rush and so it was very untested.

Comment: @adamretter I agree the requirements are very unclear. I just made a different guess from yours.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
count(tokenize($string1, "\s+")[. = tokenize($string2, "\s+")])
```

This is the number of words in the first string that also appear in the second string. Which might or might not be what you actually want. For example, if the two strings are "the more the merrier" and "the rite of spring", the answer will be 2.